# Sheaf of compact Hausdorff spaces but not a condensed anima

Tags: higher-category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory, infinity-topos-theory, condensed-mathematics

Consider the site $\mathbf{CHaus}$ of compact Hausdorff spaces together with the finitely jointly surjective families of maps as coverings. Restriction induces an equivalence of categories $$ \mathbf{Sh}_{\mathbf{An}}(\mathbf{CHaus})^{\mathrm{hyp}} \simeq \mathbf{Sh}_{\mathbf{An}}(\mathbf{ExtrDisc}) = \mathbf{Cond(An)} $$ also known as the *condensed anima*.

What is an example of a sheaf $F: \mathbf{CHaus}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathbf{An}$ which is not a hypersheaf?

Comment: You're probably aware, but in the (almost) equivalent language of pyknotic and pseupyknotic spaces, this is also claimed in Barwick and Haine, [*Pyknotic objects I*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09966), Warning 2.2.7. No example is given there, presumably because it's pretty hard to write down anything at all that is not constructed from representables.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Thank you for your comment! I'm aware indeed, maybe it would already be a good start to provide a proof of the claim that $\mathbf{Sh}_{\mathbf{An}}(\mathbf{CHaus})$ is not hypercomplete which I already cannot see.

Comment: Hmm, I thought that was the same statement, as a hypersheaf is the same thing as a hypercomplete object [HTT, Corollary 6.5.3.13], and an $\infty$-topos is hypercomplete if and only if all of its objects are [HTT, text before Lemma 6.5.2.9 and text before Remark 6.5.2.11].

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn It's funny, my master's thesis supervisor said the same thing! I was rather thinking of the following though: In the beginning question I asked for an explicit example of such a sheaf but possibly there is an abstract argument (without explicitly constructing an example) that shows that $\mathbf{Sh}_{\mathbf{An}}(\mathbf{CHaus})$ is not hypercomplete (maybe by showing that it doesn't have some property that hypercomplete topoi would have?).